# Creating a new df joining two data frames (iterating each row) with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a couple of decent sized dataframes that look like:

**df_B**

```
id     start_time                   end_time                     side      cost 
1234   2021-01-01 16:00:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:02:00.100000   BUY       100
1564   2021-01-01 16:05:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:10:00.100000   BUY       111
7535   2021-01-01 16:40:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:55:00.100000   BUY       124
9999   2021-01-01 16:44:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:45:00.100000   BUY       128
```

**df_S**

```
id     start_time                   end_time                     side      cost 
5366   2021-01-01 16:00:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:02:00.100000   SELL       100
4533   2021-01-01 16:05:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:08:00.100000   SELL       105
4532   2021-01-01 16:20:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:50:00.100000   SELL       122
5827   2021-01-01 16:30:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:35:00.100000   SELL       123
```

I would like to create a new dataframe such that:
for each id in df_B:
if df_S.cost <= df_B.cost
& df_S.start_time <= df_B.end_time

Eg:
Desired output:

```
id     start_time                   end_time                     side      cost  id_S   start_time_S             end_time_S             side_S      cost_S 
1234   2021-01-01 16:00:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:02:00.100000   BUY       100   5366   2021-01-01 16:00:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:02:00.100000   SELL       100
1564   2021-01-01 16:05:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:10:00.100000   BUY       111   4533   2021-01-01 16:05:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:08:00.100000   SELL       105
7535   2021-01-01 16:40:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:55:00.100000   BUY       124
9999   2021-01-01 16:44:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:45:00.100000   BUY       128
```

Could you please advise how I can efficiently write this, for a large dataframe

Comment: how is your desired output different from df_B

Comment: As you can see, scrolling to the right of the desired output df, you can see sell side entries being joined to the buy side ones..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the match of record with id `1564`, I believe you want to create a 1:1 matching, given that other records satisfy the matching conditions as well.

The closest function I believe you are looking for is [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=pa).

However, it only allows for merging based on one condition. It is not implemented for merging based on two conditions. And this is for good reason, I believe.

For example, why does your expected result match `4533` to `1564`, but not `5366` instead, given that both satisfy the merge condition? In this case, you may argue that `1564`'s values for `start_time` and `cost` are both closer to the respective values of `4533` compared to `5366`, i.e., `1564` is a "better match".

But, in general, what rule would you want to impose in case the matching condition is satisfied for two candidate records, say `A` and `B`, where, for example, record `A` is a "better match" with respect to condition 1 and record `B` with respect to 2? You would have to provide more information/rules to write an algorithm.

If you want 1:m matching and you have a decent data size, consider `SQLite`, I find it to more appropriate for such problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a mask then merge outer on index.
If you don't have an index or you are using id as index, just do `df.reset_index()`

create a mask

```py
mask = df_s.cost <= df_b.cost & df_s.start_time <= df_b.end_time
```

then merge with the mask on

```py
pd.merge(df_b[mask],df_s[mask],suffixes=('_B','_S'),how = 'left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Unfortunately this method will drop the row that the conditions are untrue for any one of the 2 dataframes.

the result should be

```
 cost  id_S   start_time_S             end_time_S             side_S      cost_S 
1234   2021-01-01 16:00:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:02:00.100000   BUY       100   5366   2021-01-01 16:00:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:02:00.100000   SELL       100
1564   2021-01-01 16:05:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:10:00.100000   BUY       111   4533   2021-01-01 16:05:00.100000   2021-01-01 16:08:00.100000   SELL       105
```